# Client to edit a few pages. Mini CMS?

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system

Our client would like to be able to edit a few pages on their website that we just built.  Now I know this probably doesn't deserve something like Wordpress, but something very small probably just custom built where I store the page information in the database.

I just wanted to see if there are any suggestions to make sure I have the right plan here and see if there are any security issues or better solutions.

So I figured I would just store the 4-5 pages text in a database using TEXT.  Then I would create a little backend page for them to log in and have access to edit the content with a simple WYSIWYG editor, and hit submit and it updates the database.

I know it sounds super simple but is there any problems doing it like this? Is there a better solution out there without having to implement the whole site like Wordpress?

---

**Edit:** Thank you for your responses.  I ended up going with PageLime (thank you Maggie!)  I remember hearing about it before, I read that article on nettuts a while back but never really acted on it but PageLime is PERFECT for what I was looking for.

It does exactly what I need and more!  I love it, I recommend it to anyone :)

Comment: For such a simple website it should be good. For security, put the editor site behind an administration area, where the user has to log-in, in order to change data.

Comment: you could take a look at http://pagelime.com/
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/cmss/allow-your-clients-to-update-their-websites-on-the-go/

Comment: Thanks Maggie, I ended up going with PageLime!  It's perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took exactly the same approach in my project. Users enter/edit their text in separate application and store it into database. And this data is later read and inserted directly into HTML.

Later they wanted to add images and hyperlinks and do more advanced stuff for some pages so I started to use CushyCMS - it's free and quite simple to use

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit, too late. Its here for anyone else stumbling on the same question. 
I found **[CouchCMS](http://www.couchcms.com/)** do the same job but self hosted.

Nonetheless, CushyCMS and PageLime are also very good